# Undo an operation in Maya API

Tags: c++, maya, maya-api

In my Maya .mll file I have the following:

```
void doIt()
{
    MGlobal::executeCommand("polyMapCut -ch 1 pCube1.e[2];");
}

void undoIt()
{
    MStreamUtils::stdOutStream() << "Undo is called";
    MGlobal::executeCommand("undo;");
}
```

This are all registered to the command `runCut` inside an MEL script.

Inside the Maya script editor, after executing `runCut` and then trying to undo it:

`"Undo is called"` is displayed, meaning `UndoIt()` works, but I then get an error saying that `"The undo queue is turned off."`

Is it the way that I call `undo` that is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

It means you've disabled the undo queue, so can't currently undo. To turn it back on again, you can do:

```
undoInfo -st 1;
```

Comment: It still gives the same error. I suspect the thing is not due purely to the undo queue being turned off, as doing operations normally in the scene and then undoing it works.

Comment: Have you checked if isUndoable vritual function returns True?